# Relations and ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have one stupid question.

I have 2 tables in DB, and in one table (example: report) I have foreign key from table "warehouse". I want to get the name of warehouse in my report.

I used this method to find something from other table:

```
@report = ReportMain.find(params[:id])

@warehouse = Warehouse.find(@report.warehouse_id).name
```

My question is, there is some simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the relation between these tables:

```
@warehouse = @report.warehouse
```

Would work if a Warehouse `belongs_to` to a Report, and a Report `has_one` or `has_many` Warehouse. Be sure to check out the [Association Basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) in the Ruby on Rails guides, it's an awesome read.

Comment: Warehouse has_many :reports and report belongs_to :warehouse. It's One to many relation

Comment: if a Report belongs_to a Warehouse, my answer still sticks, and should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In order to take advantage of Rails' "magic", you need to set up your associations in your models.

In your `ReportMain` model, put:

```
belongs_to: warehouse
```

In your `Warehouse` model, put:

```
has_one :report_main
```

Then, you can do something like:

```
@warehouse = @report.warehouse
```